# Opencv in Maven Project

Tags: maven, opencv

I have a question please,when using opencv in a Maven project,do I need to install opencv in my computer ? 
I've added the dependency in pom.xml and the dependency was added but when running the code it said no opencv in java.library.path.  It needs to specify the dll path
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> "When using opencv in a Maven project, do I need to install opencv in
>   my computer?"

**Yes, you do.**

When adding dependencies you are telling the compiler where to find the library you want to use. You may not need the library to be accessible from your computer, but the files definitely need to be accessible from your project directory.

Links that may help:

- [Maven: Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)
- [Understanding Dependencies](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/ood/understanding-dependencies.html)